# How do I add a custom authorization header to my JSON request?

Tags: android, json, request, header, authorization

I need to send a request that authorizes the user by providing a bearer token. How can i add a header to my request that contains this bearer token.

This is what my request looks like:

`JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq2 = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                                        personUrl, null,
                                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                            }
                                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                        //something
                                    }
                                });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override one more method, which is getHeaders().

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
    params.put("Accept-Language", "en"); //add as many headers as you want
    return params;
}
```

Little tip here is, stop using volley and use Retrofit Instead. Its much better, clean and easy. 
You can check this course to learn retrofit in detail: **[Android Retrofit Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtCmFEaQENc&list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hhGfJw-IQCm6kjywmuJX4Rh&index=13)**.